# Hello, how do I copy text and paste it into another line in notepad?

Tags: notepad

how do I copy text and paste it into another line in notepad?
need to copy the text between "0;" and ";"
then paste it in the desired location.
How do I do that?
tried using regular expressions, but could not.

example:
filename new.txt

```
Start

1-    0; Text 1 ;
2-    line 1
3-    line 1
4-    line 3
5-  
6-    0; Text 2 ;
7-    line 1
8-    line 1
9-    line 3
10-  
11-  0; Text 3 ;
12-  line 1
13-  line 1
14-  line 3

end
```

change to:
filename new.txt

```
Start

1-    0; Text 1 ;
2-    line 1
3-    line 1
4-    line 3 Text 1
5-  
6-    0; Text 2 ;
7-    line 1
8-    line 1
9-    line 3Text 2
10-  
11-  0; Text 3 ;
12-  line 1
13-  line 1
14-  line 3 Text 3

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a question for Stack Overflow.

1. Select the text by clicking and dragging, making the desired portion blue.
2. Right-click the selection.
3. Click "Copy."
4. Move the cursor to the desired position, and right-click again.
5. Click "Paste."

Alternatively, you can press `Ctrl` and `C` to copy, and `Ctrl` and `V` to past.

Comment: hello, then it was easy.
the problem is that I need to do this in about 3,000 different words. they are among 0; and ;                                                                                  and I need to move each word to a line (which has a text as a reference, called 'line 3')